# Python Pandas - copying data from one sheet and appending at the end of another

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a workbook called TEMPLATE.xlsx. In this workbook i have two tabs, ALL_DATA_RAW and WEEKLY_DATA_RAW. get my data from an API and feed it into Weekly_Data tab by opening TEMPLATE workbook, deleting the WEEKLY_DATA_RAW, then recreating that same tab and storing the df from API into that tab.

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('TEMPLATE.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('TEMPLATE.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
book.remove(book.get_sheet_by_name('WEEKLY_DATA_RAW'))
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, "WEEKLY_DATA_RAW", index = False)
writer.save()
```

First question is, is there a way I can accomplish this without deleting and recreating the WEEKLY_DATA_RAW? Instead i would prefer to clear the current data in it and store df in it?

Second question is, after i store the data into WEEKLY_DATA_RAW i have to also append that data into ALL_DATA_RAW tab at the bottom.

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue you can create a temp val to hold all your data without changing it and for the next issue if im understanding correctly is to combine/concatenate excel files data. Look at this video and let me know if that is what youre looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWaerL6-OiU